# How to measure the rate of rise of a variable

Tags: c++, loops

I am reading in a temperature value every 1 second/minute (this rate is not crucial). I want to measure this temperature so that if it begins to rise rapidly above a certain threshold I perform an action.

If the temperature rises above 30 degrees ( at any rate ) I increase the fan speed.

I think I must do something like set old temperature to new temp and then each time it loops set old temp to the current temp of the engine. But I am not sure if I need to use arrays for the engine temp or not.

Comment: What is 1 second/minute?

Comment: @HappyCoder: "This rate is not crucial". "At any rate".

Comment: This depends on the nature of your data. What is the noise level? What is a "rapid rise" in relation to that. It is quite likely, that you will like to smoothen your data to reduce noise before computing the rate of increase. And that will require you to store some amount of history.

Comment: As far as I know, it is an analog input from a temperature sensor. I didnt think of noisem, so thanks for mentioning that! Is it possible to create a simple program that doesnt factor in noise, and then incorporate it later?

Comment: @FrankWhite _"... if it begins to rise rapidly ..."_ So if it doesn't rise _rapidly_ you don't need to take an action and just let the system overheat at a slow rate? If it's going over the threshold, start the fan, and increase fan speed proportionally to the actual temperature.

Comment: Yeh actually that becomes a lot more simple then, so I can just assign a fan speed to a range of temperature. In this design there is already a limit set at 40 to open the louvre and turn on the main fans but I could do 30-33 low fan speed, 34-36 medium fan speed, 37-39 high fan speed. Is this an inefficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can store just one old sample, then check difference like in:

```
bool isHot(int sample) {
    static int oldSample = sample;
    return ((sample > 30) || (sample - oldSample > threshold));
}
```

It's OK from C point of view, but very bad from metrology point of view. You should consider some conditioning of your signal (in this case temperature) to smothen out any spikes.

Of course you can add signal conditioning letter on. For (easy) example look at Simple Moving Avarage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

If you want control the fan speed "right way" you should consider learning a bit about PID controller: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller

Simple discrete PID:
PidController.h:

```
class PidController
{
public:
    PidController();
    double sim(double y);
    void UpdateParams(double kp, double ki, double kd);
    void setSP(double setPoint) { m_setPoint = setPoint; } //set current value of r(t)

private:
    double m_setPoint; //current value of r(t)
    double m_kp;
    double m_ki;
    double m_kd;
    double m_outPrev;
    double m_errPrev[2];
};
```

PidController.cpp

```
#include "PidController.h"

PidController::PidController():ControllerObject()
{
    m_errPrev[0] = 0;
    m_errPrev[1] = 0;
    m_outPrev = 0;
}
void PidController::UpdateParams(double kp, double ki, double kd)
{
    m_kp = kp;
    m_ki = ki;
    m_kd = kd;
}
//calculates PID output 
//y - sample of y(t)
//returns sample of u(t)
double PidController::sim(double y)
{
    double out; //u(t) sample
    double e = m_setPoint - y; //error
    out = m_outPrev + m_kp * (e - m_errPrev[0] + m_kd * (e - 2 * m_errPrev[0] + m_errPrev[1]) + m_ki * e);

    m_outPrev = out; //store previous output
    //store previous errors
    m_errPrev[1] = m_errPrev[0];
    m_errPrev[0] = e;

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Konserw, I know PID controllers quite well, but my only experience using them has been using MATLAB I have never written a code in c++ for it! I will take a look at that now :)

Comment: is there any chance you could add some comments to that code please?

Comment: now fixed missing m_setPoint - it was inherited from abstract ControllerClas in project I've copied it from ;)
Added some comments, but most of it is self-explanatory when you are looking on [wiki image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/PID_en_updated_feedback.svg/720px-PID_en_updated_feedback.svg.png)